# Showing real memory used on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory, malware

I bought a lenovo ideapad 330s laptop. It has 4GB of ram. When I turn on the computer after I bought it, I could play call of dutty black-ops 2. It stopped working then I gave it to the seller to fix it. When the seller gave me back the computer 2 days ago, they formatted the disk and install another windows 10. When I turn on the computer without executing my own programs,  I can see it using 50% of the 4GB ram. But Task manager cannot give me information about the memory usage. If I execute just Google Chrome, the ram usage get to 67%. executing any Ide like Visual studio code or netbeans, it goes to like 98%.

I just get paranoia that maybe they installed a virus on the computer that I can't know about. I'm using AVG antivirus but no virus has been detected.

Is there any program that can show all the ram usage by all executed processes?

Here are some screenshots:

Task manager:

[image]

Rammap:

[image]

[image]